# Marshal by bleed/reference/value?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have heard about marshal by reference, marshal by bleed and marshal by value. What exactly are the differences between these 3? I know that these are used when transporting data across appdomains/serialization but not much more.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The different forms of marshaling are used to describe how objects behave when they are passed between `AppDomain` instances via normal function calls.  An `AppDomain` is often known as a light weight process and provides an isolated container for managed objects to run in.  Here's a quick breakdown of the different types

### Marshal By Reference

All types which derive from `MarshalByRefObject` will marshal by reference.  These object instances do not travel between `AppDomain` instances.  They are allocated in a specific `AppDomain` and do not leave it.

When a reference to a `MarshalByRefObject` is passed across an `AppDomain` boundary a proxy is created in the target `AppDomain`.  This proxy can be used to manipulate the object in the original `AppDomain` but the object itself is not directly accessible.

### Marshal By Value

Essentially the opposite of `MarshalByRefObject`.  When these values are passed across `AppDomain` boundaries they are serialized via binary serialization and deserialized in the target `AppDomain` instance.  The result is two, hopefully, independent values.  One in each domain.

### Marshal By Bleed

Certain classes of types are known as Domain Neutral.  In particular `string`, `Type` and other reflection members.  These objects do not live in a particular `AppDomain` and references to them can be freely shared between them.  They are similar to marshal by reference in that duplicates are not created but proxies are not created either.  Instead the direct reference is shared between `AppDomain` instances.

You should take a look at Joe Duffy's blog entry on the subject

- http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/08/21/dont-lock-on-marshalbybleed-objects/